# Receive a task notification for any task assigned to you - your group or not

Tags: 2010, alert, tasks

Is there a general place to set up notifications on tasks so that anyone who has a task assigned to them will receive a notification - not dependant on if they have set up an alert for that list or not?

Example: Jane works in Design. She has no access to Fincance. But Finance has assigned her the task of designing a presentation. Finance has no access to Design. How would Fincance task Jane and she would receive a notification?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think task lists will do this by default.  Under advanced settings there is an option to send email when ownership is assigned.  I believe this option is enabled by default.  So a user wouldn't need to setup an alert beforehand.  I do think the user would need to have access to the task list in order to receive the email.

Cool new feature in SP 2013 mysites is it will aggregate all of the tasks assigned to you in the farm (or your farm's search realm) on a page called my tasks.  Pretty cool stuff.

Comment: Thanks for this. I think there must be an issue with the pemissions somewhere as I did as you suggested and when creating a new test task it stated at the top that an email notification would be sent out to the assigned user. But no email received to users with or without permissions to see the list.

Just been reading about the My tasks in 2013 today. Looks like just what I need...